# Chrome Options not used by browser

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

We are creating UI Tests with Selenium, Chrome and Specflow and we are observing the issue that the defined Chrome Browser Options are not used.

We have following hook class created.

```
[Binding]
public class FeatureLevelHooks
{
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void BeforeFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("** BeforeFeature **");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--icongnito");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");

        IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        featureContext.Add("webDriver", webDriver);
    }

    [AfterFeature]
    public static void AfterFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        var driver = featureContext.Get<IWebDriver>("webDriver");

        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Everything works completely fine, the only thing is that the options is used.

Any idea why that is happening?
Thanks
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

My fault, there is an typo on one option.

Wrong line: `options.AddArgument("--icongnito");`

Correct Line: `options.AddArgument("--incognito");`

Hope that is helpfull for other people.
Joerg